# Using google translate in android application

Tags: java, android, nlp, translation, google-translate

I want to use google translate API on my android project. Below are my codes. It works as java project but when I try it on android device, project stopped. What is the reason?
 I added [googletranslateapi-1.0.jar](https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/downloads/detail?name=gtranslateapi-1.0.jar&can=2&q=),

**translator.java**

```
package com.example.calendar;

import com.gtranslate.Language;
import com.gtranslate.Translator;

public class translator {

    public String translate(String text) {
        Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
        String text2 = translate.translate(text, Language.TURKISH,
                Language.ENGLISH);
        return text2;
    }

}
```

In mainactivity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

if (requestCode == VR_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ArrayList<String> suggestedWords = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            text = suggestedWords.get(0);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            ClassificationActivity classificationActivity = new ClassificationActivity();
            String category = classificationActivity.control(text);
            translator trans = new translator();
            String ingtext = trans.translate(text);

            CalendarEvent cv = new CalendarEvent();
            Date date = new Date();
            ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, CalendarEvent
                    .toICSContentValues(cv, date.getTime(), category));
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ingtext, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding to this question as it is still getting a fair number of views and hasn't seen an accept.

The google-api-translate-java library from the Google Code Archive is out of date and should no longer be used. You should now be using the 
[Translate API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2) which is a component of the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)

An example of usage:

```
GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("link"); 
GoogleAPI.setKey("key"); 
String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Some text", Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems Google have opened up the translate API via a [web service](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html). This way, you can do the translation yourself and show it within your app. It's a bit more work, but it should do the job.

You could look at [google-api-translate-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) if you want to spare yourself from writing an API wrapper.

OR USE BELOW EXAMPLE

```
i.setComponent(
    new ComponentName(
        "com.google.android.apps.translate",
        "com.google.android.apps.translate.translation.TranslateActivity"));
```

The difference is that "translation" has been added before "TranslateActivity"

So my final version, including hard-coded translation from Spanish to English, is:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.putExtra("key_text_input", "Me gusta la cerveza");
i.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
i.putExtra("key_language_from", "es");
i.putExtra("key_language_to", "en");
i.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
i.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
i.setComponent(
    new ComponentName(
        "com.google.android.apps.translate",
        "com.google.android.apps.translate.translation.TranslateActivity"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i wrote these codes in onActivityResult column i got text this way Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   String txt = extras.getString("key_text_output");   but when i toast these, nothing appears and project stopped

Comment: Have you checked above link in this answer??? Or see this api link https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Answer (score 0):

Try using ACTION_SEND:

```
private void callGoogleTranslateApps(String word, String fromLang, String toLang) {
Intent i = new Intent();`
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra("key_text_input", word);
i.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
i.putExtra("key_language_from", fromLang);
i.putExtra("key_language_to", toLang);
i.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
i.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);`
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.translate", "com.google.android.apps.translate.TranslateActivity"));
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: what is `key_from_floating_window`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> arraylist_src_code = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arraylist_dst_code = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arraylist_src_languages = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arraylist_dst_languages = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> map_src_country = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> map_dst_country = new HashMap<>();
    String src_language, dst_language, src_code, dst_code;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        arraylist_src_code.add("af");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sq");
        arraylist_src_code.add("am");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ar");
        arraylist_src_code.add("hy");
        arraylist_src_code.add("as");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ay");
        arraylist_src_code.add("az");
        arraylist_src_code.add("bm");
        arraylist_src_code.add("eu");
        arraylist_src_code.add("be");
        arraylist_src_code.add("bn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("bho");
        arraylist_src_code.add("bs");
        arraylist_src_code.add("bg");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ca");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ceb");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ny");
        arraylist_src_code.add("zh-CN");
        arraylist_src_code.add("zh-TW");
        arraylist_src_code.add("co");
        arraylist_src_code.add("hr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("cs");
        arraylist_src_code.add("da");
        arraylist_src_code.add("dv");
        arraylist_src_code.add("doi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("nl");
        arraylist_src_code.add("en");
        arraylist_src_code.add("eo");
        arraylist_src_code.add("et");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ee");
        arraylist_src_code.add("fil");
        arraylist_src_code.add("fi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("fr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("fy");
        arraylist_src_code.add("gl");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ka");
        arraylist_src_code.add("de");
        arraylist_src_code.add("el");
        arraylist_src_code.add("gn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("gu");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ht");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ha");
        arraylist_src_code.add("haw");
        arraylist_src_code.add("he");
        arraylist_src_code.add("hi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("hmn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("hu");
        arraylist_src_code.add("is");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ig");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ilo");
        arraylist_src_code.add("id");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ga");
        arraylist_src_code.add("it");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ja");
        arraylist_src_code.add("jv");
        arraylist_src_code.add("kn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("kk");
        arraylist_src_code.add("km");
        arraylist_src_code.add("rw");
        arraylist_src_code.add("gom");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ko");
        arraylist_src_code.add("kri");
        arraylist_src_code.add("kmr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ckb");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ky");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lo");
        arraylist_src_code.add("la");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lv");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ln");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lt");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lg");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lb");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mk");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mg");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ms");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ml");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mt");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mni-Mtei");
        arraylist_src_code.add("lus");
        arraylist_src_code.add("mn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("my");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ne");
        arraylist_src_code.add("no");
        arraylist_src_code.add("or");
        arraylist_src_code.add("om");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ps");
        arraylist_src_code.add("fa");
        arraylist_src_code.add("pl");
        arraylist_src_code.add("pt");
        arraylist_src_code.add("pa");
        arraylist_src_code.add("qu");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ro");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ru");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sm");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sa");
        arraylist_src_code.add("gd");
        arraylist_src_code.add("nso");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("st");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sn");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sd");
        arraylist_src_code.add("si");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sk");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sl");
        arraylist_src_code.add("so");
        arraylist_src_code.add("es");
        arraylist_src_code.add("su");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sw");
        arraylist_src_code.add("sv");
        arraylist_src_code.add("tg");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ta");
        arraylist_src_code.add("tt");
        arraylist_src_code.add("te");
        arraylist_src_code.add("th");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ti");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ts");
        arraylist_src_code.add("tr");
        arraylist_src_code.add("tk");
        arraylist_src_code.add("tw");
        arraylist_src_code.add("uk");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ur");
        arraylist_src_code.add("ug");
        arraylist_src_code.add("uz");
        arraylist_src_code.add("vi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("cy");
        arraylist_src_code.add("xh");
        arraylist_src_code.add("yi");
        arraylist_src_code.add("yo");
        arraylist_src_code.add("zu");

        arraylist_src_languages.add("Afrikaans");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Albanian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Amharic");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Arabic");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Armenian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Assamese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Aymara");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Azerbaijani");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Bambara");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Basque");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Belarusian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Bengali");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Bhojpuri");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Bosnian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Bulgarian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Catalan");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Cebuano");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Chichewa");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Chinese (Simplified)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Chinese (Traditional)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Corsican");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Croatian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Czech");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Danish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Dhivehi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Dogri");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Dutch");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("English");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Esperanto");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Estonian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Ewe");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Filipino");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Finnish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("French");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Frisian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Galician");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Georgian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("German");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Greek");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Guarani");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Gujarati");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Haitian Creole");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hausa");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hawaiian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hebrew");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hindi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hmong");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Hungarian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Icelandic");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Igbo");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Ilocano");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Indonesian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Irish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Italian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Japanese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Javanese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kannada");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kazakh");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Khmer");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kinyarwanda");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Konkani");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Korean");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Krio");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kurdish (Kurmanji)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kurdish (Sorani)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Kyrgyz");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Lao");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Latin");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Latvian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Lingala");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Lithuanian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Luganda");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Luxembourgish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Macedonian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Malagasy");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Malay");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Malayalam");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Maltese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Maori");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Marathi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Meiteilon (Manipuri)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Mizo");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Mongolian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Myanmar (Burmese)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Nepali");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Norwegian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Odiya (Oriya)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Oromo");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Pashto");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Persian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Polish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Portuguese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Punjabi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Quechua");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Romanian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Russian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Samoan");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sanskrit");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Scots Gaelic");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sepedi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Serbian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sesotho");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Shona");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sindhi");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sinhala");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Slovak");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Slovenian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Somali");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Spanish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Sundanese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Swahili");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Swedish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Tajik");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Tamil");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Tatar");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Telugu");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Thai");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Tigrinya");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Tsonga");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Turkish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Turkmen");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Twi (Akan)");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Ukrainian");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Urdu");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Uyghur");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Uzbek");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Vietnamese");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Welsh");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Xhosa");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Yiddish");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Yoruba");
        arraylist_src_languages.add("Zulu");

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist_src_languages.size(); i++) {
            map_src_country.put(arraylist_src_languages.get(i), arraylist_src_code.get(i));
        }

        arraylist_dst_code.add("af");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sq");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("am");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ar");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("hy");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("as");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ay");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("az");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("bm");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("eu");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("be");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("bn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("bho");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("bs");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("bg");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ca");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ceb");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ny");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("zh-CN");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("zh-TW");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("co");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("hr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("cs");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("da");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("dv");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("doi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("nl");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("en");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("eo");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("et");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ee");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("fil");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("fi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("fr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("fy");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("gl");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ka");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("de");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("el");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("gn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("gu");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ht");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ha");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("haw");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("he");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("hi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("hmn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("hu");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("is");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ig");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ilo");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("id");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ga");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("it");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ja");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("jv");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("kn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("kk");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("km");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("rw");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("gom");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ko");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("kri");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("kmr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ckb");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ky");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lo");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("la");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lv");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ln");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lt");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lg");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lb");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mk");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mg");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ms");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ml");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mt");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mni-Mtei");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("lus");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("mn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("my");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ne");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("no");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("or");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("om");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ps");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("fa");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("pl");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("pt");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("pa");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("qu");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ro");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ru");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sm");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sa");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("gd");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("nso");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("st");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sn");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sd");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("si");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sk");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sl");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("so");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("es");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("su");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sw");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("sv");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("tg");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ta");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("tt");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("te");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("th");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ti");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ts");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("tr");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("tk");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("tw");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("uk");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ur");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("ug");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("uz");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("vi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("cy");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("xh");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("yi");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("yo");
        arraylist_dst_code.add("zu");

        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Afrikaans");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Albanian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Amharic");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Arabic");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Armenian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Assamese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Aymara");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Azerbaijani");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Bambara");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Basque");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Belarusian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Bengali");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Bhojpuri");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Bosnian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Bulgarian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Catalan");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Cebuano");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Chichewa");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Chinese (Simplified)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Chinese (Traditional)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Corsican");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Croatian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Czech");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Danish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Dhivehi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Dogri");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Dutch");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("English");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Esperanto");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Estonian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Ewe");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Filipino");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Finnish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("French");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Frisian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Galician");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Georgian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("German");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Greek");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Guarani");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Gujarati");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Haitian Creole");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hausa");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hawaiian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hebrew");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hindi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hmong");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Hungarian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Icelandic");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Igbo");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Ilocano");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Indonesian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Irish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Italian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Japanese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Javanese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kannada");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kazakh");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Khmer");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kinyarwanda");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Konkani");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Korean");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Krio");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kurdish (Kurmanji)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kurdish (Sorani)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Kyrgyz");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Lao");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Latin");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Latvian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Lingala");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Lithuanian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Luganda");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Luxembourgish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Macedonian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Malagasy");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Malay");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Malayalam");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Maltese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Maori");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Marathi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Meiteilon (Manipuri)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Mizo");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Mongolian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Myanmar (Burmese)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Nepali");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Norwegian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Odiya (Oriya)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Oromo");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Pashto");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Persian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Polish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Portuguese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Punjabi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Quechua");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Romanian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Russian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Samoan");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sanskrit");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Scots Gaelic");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sepedi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Serbian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sesotho");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Shona");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sindhi");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sinhala");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Slovak");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Slovenian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Somali");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Spanish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Sundanese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Swahili");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Swedish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Tajik");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Tamil");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Tatar");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Telugu");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Thai");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Tigrinya");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Tsonga");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Turkish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Turkmen");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Twi (Akan)");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Ukrainian");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Urdu");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Uyghur");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Uzbek");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Vietnamese");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Welsh");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Xhosa");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Yiddish");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Yoruba");
        arraylist_dst_languages.add("Zulu");

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist_dst_languages.size(); i++) {
            map_dst_country.put(arraylist_dst_languages.get(i), arraylist_dst_code.get(i));
        }

        String Sentence = "This is a test";
        src_language = "English";
        src_code = map_src_country.get(src_language);
        dst_language = "Hindi";
        dst_code = map_dst_country.get(dst_language);
        String Translation = GoogleTranslate(Sentence, src_code, dst_code);
        System.out.println("Translation = " + Translation);

    }


    private String GoogleTranslate(String SENTENCE, String SRC, String DST) {
        AtomicReference<String> TRANSLATION = new AtomicReference<>("");
        try {
            SENTENCE = URLEncoder.encode(SENTENCE, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException: ", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String finalSENTENCE = SENTENCE;
        try {
            String url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/";
            String params = "single?client=gtx&sl=" + SRC + "&tl=" + DST + "&dt=t&q=" + finalSENTENCE;
            HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(url+params));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
                String stringOfByteArrayOutputStream = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                JSONArray jSONArray = new JSONArray(stringOfByteArrayOutputStream).getJSONArray(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < jSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray jSONArray2 = jSONArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    TRANSLATION.set(TRANSLATION + jSONArray2.get(0).toString());
                }

            }
            else {
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("GoogleTranslator",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return TRANSLATION.toString();
    }
}
```

Check the complete implementation in one of my repos : https://github.com/botbahlul/android-autosrt

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than posting only code.